# Swipe delete not working on TableVIewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, uitableview

I have used [REFrostedViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController) side menu in my project . 
it uses PanGesture which conflict the swipe gesture on `TableViewCell`
i have also tried disabling its PangGusture using its property

```
self.frostedViewController.panGestureEnabled=NO;
```

but still facing the same problem .

Where  `REFrostedViewController`  extention of `UIViewController` class

**My question is**

Is there anyway to disable the super class gesture ?

Comment: I m facing the same problem :(

Comment: try to disable property of forstedViewController.panGestureEnabled = false

Answer (score 0):

Most probably REFrostedViewController side menu intercepts and blocks the gestures.

Implement the following category in the view controller. It should solve the problem.

```
@interface UIView (CellSwipeAdditions)

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;

@end

@implementation UIView (CellSwipeAdditions)
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```